# TP-Link TL-WN722N with Atheros AR9271 doesn't work on Debian 9 Stretch aarch64 (ROCK64)

Tags: networking, wifi, usb

I am trying to get my TP-Link TL-WN722N external USB wireless adapter with Atheros AR9271 working and I've tried everything I could find on the matter.
I have firmware-atheros and all the firmware-* packages installed.

Here is some data on the system:

```
root@rock64:~# modprobe ath9k_htc
modprobe: FATAL: Module ath9k_htc not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.132-1072-rockchip-ayufan-ga1d27dba5a2e
root@rock64:~# locate ath9k_htc
/lib/firmware/ath9k_htc
/lib/firmware/ath9k_htc/htc_7010-1.4.0.fw
/lib/firmware/ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw
```

```
root@rock64:~# uname -a
Linux rock64 4.4.132-1072-rockchip-ayufan-ga1d27dba5a2e #1 SMP Sat Jul 21 20:18:03 UTC 2018 aarch64 GNU/Linux
root@rock64:~# cat /etc/debian_version 
9.6
```

```
root@rock64:~# lsmod 
Module                  Size  Used by
ath9k                  86016  0
ath9k_common           32768  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              417792  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    28672  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
dw_hdmi_i2s_audio      16384  0
mali                  262144  0
ip_tables              24576  0
x_tables               32768  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  0
```

```
root@rock64:~# lsusb 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Dmesg:

```
[10688.089747] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-platform
[10688.226132] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=9271
[10688.227170] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=48
[10688.228323] usb 2-1: Product: USB2.0 WLAN
[10688.228995] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: ATHEROS
[10688.229614] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 12345
```

```
root@rock64:~# iwconfig 
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

root@rock64:~# ifconfig -a
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.205  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::dbd5:88e2:d357:b818  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ae:38:5e:a3:f1:7c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 25348  bytes 27952820 (26.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13860  bytes 2115038 (2.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 40  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8586  bytes 695302 (679.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8586  bytes 695302 (679.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@rock64:~#
```