# TL-WN722N v2 (Debian 9)

Tags: debian, wifi

I buyed a TL-WN722N v2 but it is not working on Debian 9, it is working on Windows (last reason why i using dual boot XD), so the device is working...

Is anyone here ever put it to work on debian 9?

Looking on the internet i found ppl with the same problem:
[TP-Link TL-WN722N with Atheros AR9271 doesn't work on Debian 9 Stretch aarch64 (ROCK64)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491897/tp-link-tl-wn722n-with-atheros-ar9271-doesnt-work-on-debian-9-stretch-aarch64)
https://www.clubedohardware.com.br/forums/topic/1281397-instalar-drivers-tl-wn722n-v2-debian-9/

On this last one, the guy said to update the kernel by using:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t stretch-backports install linux-image-amd64
```

He said after kernel 4.13 it should work

```
uname -r
4.14.0-0.bpo.3-amd64
```

Still not working

But if i do iwconfig, shows it:

```
wlxc025e91f6311  unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

What should i do now?

Comment: Check the installation instruction here :https://github.com/abhijeet2096/TL-WN722N-V2#installation-instruction

Comment: i've follow step by step
but not work

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

on the first reboot, shows something about is not available, but i could get, cause was too fast, not showing anymore

how to rever that things i did, to remove it?

Comment: otrz@bax:/usr/src$ sudo dkms add ./TL-WN722N-V2
Error! DKMS tree already contains: 8188eu-1.2
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
otrz@bax:/usr/src$ sudo dkms build -m 8188eu -v 1.2
Module 8188eu/1.2 already built for kernel 4.14.0-0.bpo.3-amd64/4
otrz@bax:/usr/src$ sudo dkms install -m 8188eu -v 1.2
Module 8188eu/1.2 already installed on kernel 4.14.0-0.bpo.3-amd64/x86_64
otrz@bax:/usr/src$ sudo modprobe 8188eu
otrz@bax:/usr/src$

Comment: i also tried
cd ~ && git clone https://github.com/abhijeet2096/TL-WN722N-V2 && cd TL-WN722N-V2 && sudo make clean && sudo make all && sudo make install && sudo reboot
don't change a thing still
iwconfig
enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.